# SQL: add column constraint that date must be end of month

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

SQL Server: I am looking for a way to force at database level a date column to be last day of the month (note: **not** the last day of **current** month). Is there a way to alter the table to implement this constraint?

Thank you

Comment: Checl on `day(dateadd(day, 1, dt)) = 1`

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I got Yogesh to fix his answer, which should suit what you've asked for. Feel free to upvote something of mine to say thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement the check constraint via `eomonth()` function to validate the date (i.e. end-of-month)

```
ALTER table t
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Date CHECK(<date> = eomonth(<date>))
```

Comment: Won't work with end of months that are not current one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "CHECK(<datecolumn> = eomonth(<datecolumn>))"?

Answer (score 1):

You can, however, do any of the following:

- Do your validation in a trigger. Should be after insert and update.
- Create another table with all possible end of month dates and use a foreign key for that column.

Yogesh's answer is the correct one.